# How to use subfig to produce a more complex arrangement of Figures on the page

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to produce a figure with 5 subfigures using latex and `subfig`. The first subfigure `Network` needs to be large and on the left whereas the other four are graphs and should be tiled to the same height as the Network image but to the right, i.e. so the shape of the figure as a whole produces a rectangle. Is this possible using latex?

Here is my code so far assuming all relevent images are in a folder in the ccurrent directory called `Images` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Network]{%
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ODENetwork}}
        \subfloat[$k_{delay}=0.001$]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"reduced_0.001_delaySimulation"}\label{reduceda}}
        \subfloat[$k_{delay}=0.01$]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"reduced_0.01_delaySimulation"}\label{reducedb}}\\
        \subfloat[$k_{delay}=0.1$]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"reduced_0.1_delaySimulation"}\label{reducedc}}
        \subfloat[$k_{delay}=1$]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"reduced_1_delaySimulation"}\label{reducedd}}\\
        \caption{Simulation of model described by \cref{ODE1} }
        \label{reduced}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it have to be `subfig` (which is kind of outdated) or may you use `subcaption`?

Comment: Not at all - I'm new to latex and I tried a few image packages. `subfig` was the one that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `subcaption` version. Just play with the widths to adjust to your images.

[image: subcaption]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption[Network]{ODENetwork}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \parbox{.475\textwidth}{
            \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \caption{Test 1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \caption{Test 2}
        \end{subfigure}\\
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \caption{Test 3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \caption{Test 4}
        \end{subfigure}
        }
        \caption{Simulation of model described by ODE1}\label{reduced}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CiaranWelsh You're welcome.